# Images from server does not show in listview

Tags: android, listview

Hello I am using listview and display images from server into it.

**But the problem is that all loaded images are displayed in last item one by one instead display on respective position.**

please help me to display that images in respective position

```
public class Offer_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context1;
String[] offer_title;
String[] offerimg1;
String[] mrp;
String[] offerprice;
String[] you_save;
String[] imgURLArray;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView offerimg;
 int a;
LayoutInflater inflater1;

public Offer_adapter(Context context1, String[] offer_title, String[] offerimg1, String[] mrp, String[] you_save, String[] offerprice) {
    super(context1, R.id.offer_list, offer_title);
    this.context1 = context1;
    this.offer_title = offer_title;
    this.offerimg1 = offerimg1;
    this.mrp = mrp;
    this.offerprice = offerprice;
    this.you_save = you_save;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    String offerimg;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context1.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.offer_list, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    }
    android.util.Log.v("abhi", "" + position);
    imgURLArray = new String[position + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) {
        android.util.Log.v("abhijit", "" + position);
        imgURLArray[i] = "http://www.surun.co/preost/mod_offer/images/" + offerimg1[position];
        android.util.Log.v("abhi", "" + imgURLArray[position]);
    }
   a=position;
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    TextView offertitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ofrtitle);
    TextView offermrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offeroriginal);
    offermrp.setPaintFlags(offermrp.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    TextView offersave = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveoffer);
    TextView ofrprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceoffer);
     offerimg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ofr_img);

    offertitle.setText(offer_title[position]);
    offermrp.setText("Original Price: \u20B9" + mrp[position]);
    offersave.setText("You Save: \u20B9" + you_save[position]);
    ofrprice.setText("Offer Price: \u20B9" + offerprice[position]);
   // Bitmap imageBitmap = null;


    new DownloadAsyncTask().execute(imgURLArray[position]);
    Log.v("abhi","async");
    return convertView;
}

private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            Log.v("abhi","in do background");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 270, 375, true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        if (bitmap !=null) {
        offerimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {

            offerimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.nooffer);
        }

    }
}
  }
```

All images are shown in last item one after another. I just want to show it on respective position.

Comment: use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to cache and load image bitmaps to your imageview. Also you are not using the viewholder pattern properly.

Comment: Try below link : http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134

Comment: sir could you please give some suggection in my code please it is very important for me

Answer (score 2):

you should use lazyloading instead of downloading image as bitmap.
Bitmap will create problem sometime or will give you outofmemory error in some devices

There are lots of image loading library available for android.
Have a look at these

https://github.com/square/picasso
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper
https://github.com/novoda/image-loader

Comment: I am new to android so could you please slove my problem.please give correction in my problem.

Comment: sir could you please give some suggection in my code please it is very important for me